# Approval Process status on Case Layout

Tags: case, approval-process

I have an Approval Process for custom object linked to Case object.

Do guys know if it's possible to show the approval status of this object anywhere on the Case ?

Thanks a lot,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could:

1. Define a custom field (pick list type) in your custom object for the "Approval Status" [Not sent, Waiting for approval, Approved, Rejected]
2. Set the value for the field on your approval process
   [image]
3. Include that field as a column on your custom object related list on Case Page layout

Comment: Super ! Works well. Thanks a lot.